# Loop in Crystal Report to Evaluate Details Section Multiple Times

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

For simpler illustration of the problem, please refer the table below as the detail section part of the crystal report. This is the actual records in the details section part

[image]

**In the group footer, below should be posted, what should reflect or be displayed in the group footer**

> Notes:
>
> 1. tenant2
> 2. tenant3
> 3. tenant5
> 4. tenant1
> 5. tenant4

Where in, the evaluation of the details section takes first those with "started remarks" to be followed by "ceased remarks" and displays their tenant name. ***It's like displaying the records in the details section in the footer with the order: Those with "started" remarks comes first.***

As per the normal thing, using whileprintingrecords function, it will evaluate the report from top to bottom. Is this simple evaluation of records possible?

I currently used 3 way method formula in crystal report.

Comment: Couldnt able to understand...what do you need in detail and what you need in footer

Comment: The table image above, corresponds to the actual records in the details section, now I need to display what is posted above in the group footer in that border where in those with "started" remarks come in first. @Siva

Comment: try using sub report in report footer.

Comment: Yes, and then? My plan is creating a new subreport and that will be ordered by my desired order output, is that correct?

Comment: yes correct... try with sub report

Comment: Ok, I am trying it now, I;ll give an update if it is successful

Comment: sure no problem.. let me know when you face some issue.

Comment: Hi @Siva I already did it. It is achieved now using subreport, my only problem is the speed, it became extremely slow in performance. What could be the workaround to improve it?

Comment: There are many ways to improve performance..but first need to know your report structure.

Comment: Used stored procedure as data source of both rpt file (main and sub report) they are relatively similar to each other because they produce the same output, their difference is the ordering of records in the details section. So I link the parameters of main to sub report. Will that be enough?

Comment: Another thing, report is running per group of mall location using group experts

Comment: group shouldn't be the issue... how many records that crystal is retriving in the report both main and sub report included.

Comment: roughly 20,000 records per report.